# Determine the velocity of the O fragment after the dissociation

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

> A $\ce{SO3}$ molecule is radiated with light with a wavelength of $\pu{193 nm}$, which results in photodissociation.
>
> $\ce{SO3} + \text{photon}(\lambda=\pu{193nm})\ce{-> SO2 + O}$
>
> It is measured that the $\ce{SO2}$ fragment is in the electronic ground state, but in the vibrational excited state where bending is in $v=3$.
>
> - Calculate the velocity of the $\ce{O}$ fragment after the dissociation.

I know that:

- The $\ce{SO3}$ molecule is at rest before the radiation, and we don't have to look at the rotation.
- The dissociation energy is $\pu{5.0 eV}$
- The normal vibration frequencies for $\ce{SO2}$ is $\omega_1= \pu{1151 cm^{-1}}$ (sym stretch), $\omega_2= \pu{518 cm^{-1}}$ (bending) and $\omega_3= \pu{1362 cm^{-1}}$ (asym stretch)

My first thought was to approach it like the photoelectric effect where you can determine the velocity of the ejected electron. But I can't seem to figure out how to do it using the dissociation energy and vibrational modes. I hope someone can help me with this?

Comment: Your instinct is correct. Convert all units into a common energy unit. Then subtract the vibrational energy remaining in $\ce{SO2}$ from the incoming photon energy. The result is the kinetic energy of $\ce{O}$. Convert that into a velocity.

Comment: What about the dissociation energy? Do I have to subtract that as well?

Comment: If I subtract it as well, I get the velocity to around 3510 m/s

Comment: Yes, of course, you also have to subtract the dissociation energy.